# How to make product image required and minimum 1 or maximum 6 images

Tags: magento2.3, product-images, required

I am using Magento 2.3 and creating a product doesn't need any image. How do I make it required?

Comment: If you want to image required, you can set `Values Required` to `yes` for `Image Gallery` Attribute.

Comment: Hi pawan. I am using vendor marketplace extension. In vendor login, I want product image required. How can I change gallery.html file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of steps to do here but they could be implemented:

1. Set the **Media Gallery** `Values Required` to `Yes` like the following
   [image]

This will make the image required for creating new services, but I found this field has validation issues while updating so I believe you need to create your own plugin to handle its validation yourself.

2. In your `di.xml` file add the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Validator">
         <plugin name="worxmart_service_validate_media_gallery"
                 type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\ValidateMediaGallery"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then add the following to your `ValidateMediaGallery.php` class:

```
<?php

namespace Vednor\Extension\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class ValidateMediaGallery
{
    /**
    * @param Validator $subject
    * @param Product $product
    * @param RequestInterface $request
    * @param DataObject $response
    * @return array
    * @throws LocalizedException
    */
    public function beforeValidate(Validator $subject, Product $product, RequestInterface $request, DataObject $response): array
    {
        $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute(ProductInterface::MEDIA_GALLERY);
        $attrCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
        $productData = $request->getPost('product', []);

        if (empty($productData[$attrCode])) {
            $label = $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel();
            throw new LocalizedException(
                 __('The "%1" attribute value is empty. Set the attribute and try again.', $label)
            );
        }

        $mediaGalleryEmpty = true;
        // To avoid deleting all product pics
        foreach ($productData[$attrCode]['images'] as $image) {
            if (empty($image['removed'])) {
                $mediaGalleryEmpty = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($mediaGalleryEmpty) {
            $label = $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel();
            throw new LocalizedException(
                __('The "%1" attribute value is empty. Set the attribute and try again.', $label)
            );
        }

        return [$product, $request, $response];
    }
}
```

3. For setting the maximum number I believe you need to overwrite the file uploader by overwriting the method `add` for `$('#fileupload').fileupload()` to stop adding if it gets to the maximum.

**Hint:** this answer is open for contribution as I wish it to help someone.